# How is theistic evolution and the fall of man compatible?

Tags: evolution

All scientific evidence suggests evolution did happen, or something very similar. Of course, every theory has its flaws, including evolution, but how is the fall of man conpatible with evolution? Even if it is interpreted metaphorically, there would have been death before humans were around, so how can the fall of man be compatible with the theory of evolution?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange, we are glad you are here.  When you have a minute, be sure to check out the [site tour](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/tour) and read up on how this site is [a little different](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/1808/how-we-are-different-than-other-sites) than other sites around the web. *This is not a comment on the quality of your question, but rather a standard welcome message.*